# htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect añadir un HtmlOption

Tags: java, scrapy, html-select

Estoy tratando de hacer logging a una web mediante java y quiero seleccionar un valor de una lista HtmlSelect pero en la web los HtmlOption de ese HtmlSelect se inyectan por javascript.

Lo que quiero es ponerle como valor a ese HtmlSelect un string:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

    HtmlPage page = client.getPage(loginUrl);

    HtmlSelect inputPassword = page.getFirstByXPath("//select[@id='cl_postal_code']");
    HtmlOption autreCauseSelect = inputPassword.getOptionByValue("15000");
    inputPassword.setSelectedAttribute(autreCauseSelect, true);
```

Pero esto no funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado. Le he inyectado los valores por javaScript de la siguiente forma:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    HtmlPage page = client.getPage(loginUrl);
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000);

    page.executeJavaScript("javascript: {" +
            "   var arrPostalCodes = new Array();\n" + 
            "   arrPostalCodes = [\"05001\",\"05002\",\"05003\",\"05004\",\"05005\",\"05140\",\"05160\",\"05192\",\"05194\",\"05195\",\"05196\",\"05197\",\"05289\",\"05520\",\"15001\",\"15002\",\"15003\",\"15004\",\"15005\",\"15006\",\"15007\",\"15008\",\"15009\",\"15010\",\"15011\",\"15100\",\"15102\",\"15105\",\"15106\",\"15107\",\"15108\",\"15109\",\"15125\",\"15130\",\"15139\",\"15140\",\"15141\",\"15142\",\"15144\",\"15145\",\"15146\",\"15147\",\"15148\",\"15151\",\"15154\",\"15155\",\"15160\",\"15165\",\"15166\",\"15168\",\"15169\",\"15171\",\"15172\",\"15173\",\"15174\",\"15175\",\"15176\",\"15177\",\"15178\",\"15179\",\"15180\",\"15181\",\"15182\",\"15189\",\"15190\",\"15191\",\"15198\",\"15199\",\"15200\",\"15210\",\"15211\",\"15212\",\"15213\",\"15220\",\"15228\",\"15229\",\"15270\",\"15280\",\"15281\",\"15296\",\"15300\",\"15310\",\"15314\",\"15315\",\"15316\",\"15318\",\"15319\",\"15320\",\"15325\",\"15326\",\"15327\",\"15328\",\"15329\",\"15337\",\"15340\",\"15347\",\"15350\",\"15357\",\"15380\",\"15388\",\"15401\",\"15402\",\"15403\",\"15404\",\"15405\",\"15406\",\"15490\",\"15500\",\"15530\",\"15540\",\"15541\",\"15554\",\"15555\",\"15563\",\"15567\",\"15568\",\"15569\",\"15570\",\"15572\",\"15578\",\"15582\",\"15590\",\"15592\",\"15593\",\"15594\",\"15595\",\"15596\",\"15597\",\"15600\",\"15607\",\"15609\",\"15613\",\"15614\",\"15615\",\"15616\",\"15620\",\"15621\",\"15622\",\"15623\",\"15624\",\"15627\",\"15630\",\"15637\",\"15638\",\"15639\",\"15640\",\"15650\",\"15659\",\"15660\",\"15668\",\"15669\",\"15670\",\"15679\",\"15690\",\"15701\",\"15702\",\"15703\",\"15704\",\"15705\",\"15706\",\"15707\",\"15781\",\"15782\",\"15820\",\"15830\",\"15864\",\"15866\",\"15881\",\"15883\",\"15884\",\"15885\",\"15886\",\"15890\",\"15892\",\"15893\",\"15894\",\"15895\",\"15896\",\"15897\",\"15898\",\"15940\",\"15950\",\"15959\",\"15960\",\"15965\",\"15966\",\"15967\",\"15969\",\"15970\",\"15980\",\"15993\",\"15994\",\"15999\",\"24001\",\"24002\",\"24003\",\"24004\",\"24005\",\"24006\",\"24007\",\"24008\",\"24009\",\"24010\",\"24100\",\"24110\",\"24111\",\"24112\",\"24113\",\"24114\",\"24138\",\"24139\",\"24140\",\"24141\",\"24191\",\"24193\",\"24195\",\"24196\",\"24197\",\"24198\",\"24226\",\"24228\",\"24231\",\"24390\",\"24391\",\"24395\",\"24400\",\"24401\",\"24402\",\"24403\",\"24404\",\"24410\",\"24411\",\"24412\",\"24413\",\"24414\",\"24415\",\"24416\",\"24490\",\"24491\",\"24492\",\"24496\",\"24497\",\"24498\",\"24540\",\"24548\",\"24549\",\"24700\",\"24710\",\"24711\",\"24713\",\"24715\",\"24717\",\"24718\",\"24794\",\"27001\",\"27002\",\"27003\",\"27004\",\"27141\",\"27150\",\"27153\",\"27154\",\"27160\",\"27161\",\"27192\",\"27230\",\"27290\",\"27293\",\"27294\",\"27297\",\"27298\",\"27330\",\"27340\",\"27350\",\"27375\",\"27376\",\"27377\",\"27378\",\"27379\",\"27400\",\"27424\",\"27430\",\"27460\",\"27500\",\"27510\",\"27511\",\"27512\",\"27513\",\"27514\",\"27515\",\"27516\",\"27517\",\"27518\",\"27519\",\"27520\",\"27527\",\"27528\",\"27529\",\"27530\",\"27531\",\"27532\",\"27533\",\"27540\",\"27550\",\"27554\",\"27555\",\"27556\",\"27557\",\"27558\",\"27559\",\"27595\",\"27596\",\"27700\",\"27710\",\"27711\",\"27712\",\"27713\",\"27714\",\"27715\",\"27740\",\"27742\",\"27747\",\"27748\",\"27749\",\"27752\",\"27770\",\"27774\",\"27775\",\"27776\",\"27777\",\"27778\",\"27779\",\"27780\",\"27785\",\"27786\",\"27787\",\"27788\",\"27789\",\"27790\",\"27791\",\"27792\",\"27793\",\"27794\",\"27796\",\"27797\",\"27798\",\"27800\",\"27810\",\"27811\",\"27812\",\"27814\",\"27815\",\"27816\",\"27818\",\"27820\",\"27821\",\"27822\",\"27823\",\"27824\",\"27825\",\"27826\",\"27830\",\"27832\",\"27833\",\"27834\",\"27835\",\"27836\",\"27840\",\"27841\",\"27842\",\"27843\",\"27850\",\"27860\",\"27863\",\"27864\",\"27866\",\"27867\",\"27868\",\"27869\",\"27880\",\"27888\",\"27890\",\"27892\",\"27893\",\"32001\",\"32002\",\"32003\",\"32004\",\"32005\",\"32170\",\"32300\",\"32310\",\"32313\",\"32314\",\"32315\",\"32316\",\"32317\",\"32318\",\"32336\",\"32340\",\"32348\",\"32350\",\"32356\",\"32358\",\"32420\",\"32456\",\"32500\",\"32510\",\"32514\",\"32515\",\"32516\",\"32523\",\"32534\",\"32539\",\"32570\",\"32572\",\"32573\",\"32574\",\"32575\",\"32600\",\"32613\",\"32615\",\"32616\",\"32618\",\"32619\",\"32620\",\"32626\",\"32627\",\"32630\",\"32631\",\"32632\",\"32634\",\"32635\",\"32636\",\"32637\",\"32640\",\"32641\",\"32643\",\"32644\",\"32650\",\"32692\",\"32695\",\"32696\",\"32697\",\"32698\",\"32699\",\"32710\",\"32890\",\"32911\",\"32960\",\"32981\",\"32990\",\"33812\",\"34001\",\"34002\",\"34003\",\"34004\",\"34005\",\"34006\",\"34190\",\"34192\",\"34200\",\"34220\",\"34419\",\"36001\",\"36002\",\"36003\",\"36004\",\"36005\",\"36163\",\"36164\",\"36201\",\"36202\",\"36203\",\"36204\",\"36205\",\"36206\",\"36207\",\"36208\",\"36209\",\"36210\",\"36211\",\"36212\",\"36213\",\"36214\",\"36215\",\"36300\",\"36307\",\"36308\",\"36309\",\"36310\",\"36311\",\"36312\",\"36315\",\"36316\",\"36317\",\"36318\",\"36320\",\"36340\",\"36350\",\"36360\",\"36370\",\"36378\",\"36379\",\"36380\",\"36388\",\"36389\",\"36390\",\"36391\",\"36392\",\"36393\",\"36400\",\"36410\",\"36411\",\"36412\",\"36413\",\"36414\",\"36415\",\"36416\",\"36417\",\"36418\",\"36419\",\"36440\",\"36448\",\"36450\",\"36455\",\"36456\",\"36457\",\"36458\",\"36460\",\"36470\",\"36471\",\"36472\",\"36473\",\"36474\",\"36475\",\"36500\",\"36510\",\"36511\",\"36512\",\"36514\",\"36515\",\"36516\",\"36517\",\"36518\",\"36519\",\"36579\",\"36584\",\"36588\",\"36596\",\"36598\",\"36600\",\"36610\",\"36611\",\"36612\",\"36613\",\"36614\",\"36615\",\"36616\",\"36617\",\"36618\",\"36619\",\"36620\",\"36658\",\"36659\",\"36676\",\"36680\",\"36681\",\"36682\",\"36683\",\"36684\",\"36685\",\"36686\",\"36687\",\"36688\",\"36689\",\"36700\",\"36710\",\"36711\",\"36712\",\"36713\",\"36714\",\"36715\",\"36720\",\"36721\",\"36729\",\"36730\",\"36740\",\"36790\",\"36791\",\"36840\",\"36860\",\"36861\",\"36862\",\"36863\",\"36864\",\"36865\",\"36866\",\"36867\",\"36868\",\"36869\",\"36870\",\"36890\",\"36891\",\"36892\",\"36893\",\"36895\",\"36900\",\"36910\",\"36930\",\"36939\",\"36940\",\"36954\",\"36955\",\"36958\",\"36959\",\"36960\",\"36966\",\"36967\",\"36969\",\"36970\",\"36980\",\"36990\",\"36991\",\"36992\",\"36993\",\"36995\",\"37001\",\"37002\",\"37003\",\"37004\",\"37005\",\"37006\",\"37007\",\"37008\",\"37120\",\"37181\",\"37184\",\"37185\",\"37188\",\"37189\",\"37193\",\"37194\",\"37439\",\"37796\",\"37900\",\"47001\",\"47002\",\"47003\",\"47004\",\"47005\",\"47006\",\"47007\",\"47008\",\"47009\",\"47010\",\"47011\",\"47012\",\"47013\",\"47014\",\"47015\",\"47016\",\"47130\",\"47140\",\"47151\",\"47155\",\"47193\",\"47194\",\"47195\",\"47220\",\"47400\",\"47450\",\"47454\",\"47460\",\"47463\",\"47465\",\"47490\",\"47491\",\"47492\",\"47493\",\"47494\",\"47500\",\"47509\",\"47610\"];\n" + 
            "   if (arrPostalCodes && (arrPostalCodes.descripcion === undefined)) {\n" + 
            "        arrPostalCodes.unshift({id: '', text: ''});\n" + 
            "    }"
            + "for (var i in arrPostalCodes) {\n" + 
            "                if (typeof arrPostalCodes[i] !== 'object') {\n" + 
            "                    $(\".postalCodesSelect\").append($('<option>', {\n" + 
            "                            value: arrPostalCodes[i],\n" + 
            "                            text: arrPostalCodes[i]\n" + 
            "                        })\n" + 
            "                    );\n" + 
            "                }\n" + 
            "            }" +
            "};");
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000);

    HtmlSelect selectCP = page.getFirstByXPath("//select[@id='cl_postal_code']");
    List<HtmlOption> opciones = selectCP.getOptions();
    selectCP.setSelectedAttribute(opciones.get(0), true);
```